# How to use a few conditions for the same SOQL values?

Tags: apex, soql, query, list

I have a few conditions for the same fields of record. But I get the result only from last condition. How can I use them all?

```
public List<Item__c> serch(){
    String[] filters = new String[0];

    if(String.isNotBlank(field1)) {
        Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(field1);
        filters.add('Value__c1 <=: d AND Value__c2 >=: d');
    }
    if(String.isNotBlank(field2)) {
        Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(field2);
        filters.add('Value__c1 >: d OR Value__c2 <: d');
    }
    if(String.isNotBlank(field3)) {
        Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(field3);
        filters.add('Value__c2 <: d');
    }
    return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Item__c'+
                         (filters.isEmpty()?'':' WHERE ' + String.join(filters,' AND ')));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found the bug with the dynamic SOQL scoping engine. The `:d` isn't executed until `Database.query` is called, so only the last cached version of `d` can be used. This is a bug, because technically `d` is now "out of scope", but the `Database.query` currently resolves it based on the latest version of `d` by checking the symbol table.

This is not the same as some other languages, which would resolve the value in the string itself. For example, in JavaScript, we can write:

```
var a = 5, b = `${a+a}`;
```

And we get the result of the string "10". This happens because execution is immediate. In Apex, however, the evaluation of the variable is delayed until Database.query is called.

Regardless, as you've likely guessed by now, you should move the variable in to scope, and name each one differently:

```
String[] filters = new String[0];
Decimal d1, d2, d3;
if(String.isNotBlank(field1)) {
    d1 = Decimal.valueOf(field1);
    filters.add('Value__c1 <= :d1 AND Value__c2 >= :d1');
}
if(String.isNotBlank(field2)) {
    d2 = Decimal.valueOf(field2);
    filters.add('Value__c1 > :d2 OR Value__c2 < :d2');
}
if(String.isNotBlank(field3)) {
    d3 = Decimal.valueOf(field3);
    filters.add('Value__c2 < :d3');
}
```

This avoids potential bugs in future releases if they fix the symbol table resolution bug, and will allow you to specify all three values separately.